# How do SQL relationships within Power BI work for different users?

Tags: sql, powerbi

I am creating a Power BI dashboard using someone else's Power BI dashboard. All I've done right now is used Get Data -> Power BI datasets -> clicked on the dataset that is also used by this other person's dashboard. Then when I click on the Model tab on the left hand side, I see a bunch of SQL servers linked to one another. If I start changing the SQL relationships in the model section within my Power BI Desktop, will that also change the SQL relationships within the other person's Power BI dashboard? I am a new user of Power BI and SQL so apologies if this sounds confusing. I can provide more info if necessary.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use Get Data to connect to an existing Power BI Dataset, you aren't copying the dataset. Instead, multiple reports & dashboards will all connect to the same dataset. So, in the event that you have the required permissions, you changing the dataset will change it for the other reports & dashboards (which could break them).

For more information, check out the Shared Dataset information on MS Docs (e.g. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/service-datasets-across-workspaces).